# using lstm to predict and have only one answer

Tags: python, pandas, lstm, probability

I have implemented an emotion analysis using lstm form https://www.kaggle.com/eray1yildiz/using-lstms-with-attention-for-emotion-recognition/comments

I am having wrong predictions as well as I am having a list of results as shown below:

```
['enjoy', 'lovely', 'moment']
{'joy': 0.18797465, 'satisfied': 0.19864388, 'happy': 0.18680806, 'sad': 0.20265724, 'disappointment': 0.22391614}
```

Below is the part of codes I am using for prediction:

```
      # Padding
      encoded_samples = keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(encoded_samples, maxlen=max_words)

      # Make predictions
      label_probs, attentions = model_with_attentions.predict(encoded_samples)
      label_probs = {id2label[_id]: prob for (label, _id), prob in zip(label2id.items(), label_probs[0])}
```

I want my output to be like this:

```
Input: ['enjoy', 'lovely', 'moment']
Output: 'joy'
```

Is it possible to do this? please help me guys..

Answer (score 0):

The wrong predictions are associated to the model training, however you can get a unique result by using the `argmax()` method to your `predict` result (as described here https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/5910). Without knowing the shape of `encoded_sample` I would guess that you need something like this:

```
label_probs = model_with_attentions.predict(encoded_samples)
label_pred= label_probs.argmax(axis=-1)
```

Note that here it will predict disappointment in your example.